# I an sending 3 values to a function but after the function I just want to test agains the 3th function return. How can I do this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
rows = 22
rowsMax = 21
columns = 117
columnMax = 117
status = "True"

def DrawBoard (rows,columns,status):
  if rows > rowsMax or columns > columnMax:
     status = "False"
     rows = 0
     columns = 0
  return rows,columns,status


DrawBoard(rows,columns,status)


# I want to test only the status returns from the function but get error
# DrawBoard() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'columns' and 'status'.
if DrawBoard(status) == "False":
  print("Either the row and columns maximum were excepted")
```

Comment: `if DrawBoard(rows,columns,status)[2] == "False":` would work. Even though you are only interesting in the third component of the return value, the way that you wrote the function requires 3 inputs, so `DrawBoard(status)` doesn't make sense.

Comment: As an aside, do you really want to use a string value `"True"` / `"False"` for `status` instead of a boolean?

Comment: Please try to follow [PEP8's naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) when writing python, namely that functions and variables are written in `lower_snake_case` and `PascalCase` for classes. `camelCase` isn't used in Python. Following these convention will make it easier for other programmers to read your program.

Answer (score 0):

If you write `DrawBoard(.., .., ..)` that's a function call, so you are calling the function and it returns its return values. To save these values you could do

```
ret1, ret2, ret3 = DrawBoard(rows, columns, status)
```

Now to check the third value

```
if ret3 == False:
```

You can also directly access the third return value without storing them in a variable with `DrawBoard(rows, columns, status)[2]`.

Comment: I would probably have written `_, _, ret3 = DrawBoard(rows, columns, status)`.   It's conventional to use _ as the name of a throwaway variable.

Comment: true, I just assumed they might be of use later in their script. Thanks for the clarification though.

Comment: Thanks to all of you.  A truly appreciate all of your answers.  It is very helpful and I learn allot from them. My questsion was more then asnwers.

Answer (score 0):

pushing to an object version:

```
class Board:

    def __init__(self, rows, rowsMax, columns, columnMax):
        self.rows = rows
        self.rowsMax = rowsMax
        self.columns = columns
        self.columnMax = columnMax
        self.status = True

    def drawBoard(self):
        msgError = 'Either the row and columns maximum were excepted'
        if self.rows > self.rowsMax or self.columns > self.columnMax:
            self.status = False
            self.rows = 0
            self.columns = 0
        else:
            msgError = 'All fine!'

        return msgError


if __name__ == '__main__':
    newBoard = Board(22, 21, 117, 117)
    print(newBoard.drawBoard())  # Either the row and columns maximum were excepted
    print(newBoard.status)  # False

    newBoard = Board(20, 21, 117, 117)
    print(newBoard.drawBoard())  # All fine!
    print(newBoard.status)  # True
```

Accessing the status would be as simple as `self.status` for True or False inside the class or using the object with `newBoard.status`...